# Conditionally import module using next js dynamic import, SSR doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I've a component which I am dynamically importing using `dynamic` from nextjs. And that too I want to download the bundle based on a flag that I am setting in my code (loadWirelessBundle flag in below code block). So it works fine in terms of downloading the bundle but and rendering the component **BUT it doesn't do server side rendering of the component (when loadWirelessBundle is true) even I am passing ssr = true. Does anyone know why it doesn't do server-side rendering?**

```
const WirelessPrepaid = loadWirelessBundle ? dynamic(() => import("../wireless-prepaid"), { ssr: true }) : () => null;
```

Is there something I am missing in terms of understanding dynamic import with nextjs? Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify how you set the `loadWirelessBundle` flag?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the import at the top level

```
// this goes at the top level of the module
const WirelessPrepaidDynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import("../wireless-prepaid"));

// this can be placed wherever you need it

const WirelessPrepaid = loadWirelessBundle ? WirelessPrepaidDynamicComponent  : () => null;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not required to pass `ssr` as `true` explicitly, by default it is enabled only.

Secondly, it might be the case that the value of `loadWirelessBundle` is set on the client-side rather than on the server-side, therefore the component is getting imported on the client-side. So we might have to set its value on the server-side and see if it works.